# Windows Mobile 2003 SE application in Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Prof

Tags: windows-embedded, windows-mobile-2003

I would like to know if an application developed (and working) for Windows Mobile 2003 SE is compatible with Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Prof.

In case it helps, I read WM 2003 SE is WCE 4 based and WEH 6.5 is WCE 5 based.

At this time I don't have any device with Windows EH 6.5 so I can't test it.

Any help apreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are no major issues prevening app compatibility between WM2003 and WEH6.5 or CE4 to CE5, but that does not mean that is granted that any app can run on both versions. This depends from the tools you used to develop it and from the OS features used by the app.
The Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK (same as WEH 6.5) includes emulator images, you can use the emulator to test your app compatibility.

Comment: Valter, thanks a lot. I will try the emulator. I did not develop the app but it seems not to be using very specific OS features.

Comment: Finally I could test with the device. In case it helps other people, I had no problems installing the CAB file (developed for WM2003) in a WEH 6.5 device.